# What's the criteria for deciding whether to use arrays or objects?

Tags: javascript, object

When defining data schemas in JavaScript and nesting the data inside arrays or objects what's the main advantage of choosing one over another ?

Does nesting objects inside an array have a different effect then nesting arrays inside objects ?

Is it arbitrary choosing one to nest the other inside or rather is it done quite on purpose in some cases ?

The question arose upon reading the fourth chapter of eloquent JavaScript.

Comment: Do you need a list of values (array) or something more complicated such as named keys (object)?

Comment: @DanWhite That's correct. However I am not asking the difference between those two. Rather, my question is about effects of those two practises in use.

Comment: They are two different things for two different jobs. Like asking what's the difference between a string and an integer. You can have an array of objects and an object key value as an array.